# How to call a batchfile from VBA script

Tags: vba, batch-file, permissions

I cannot call the "test1.bat" file from this visual basic script.
The only thing that i get is "Runtime error 70, access denied". Has someone had a similar outcome or experiences.

```
Sub test()

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "C:\Users\taischa\Desktop\test1.bat", windowStyle, waitOnReturn

End Sub
```

I already tried to change the .bat to .cmd file. I also tried to access the bat file through a link as admin.I can execute the Batchfile without any problem if i doubleclick the icon or call ir via cmd. I suspect the firewall to block the makro.
Maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "test.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

This makes the file invisible, but execute they. You can also type:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c test.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

To end the process when its get off.
If you need to start it with a window:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c start test.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

first, they create a object, then, they start a function of cmd, called `cmd` with the paramter `/c`, that means: the code will stop and the cmd will close while they stop running. But, first, he will start a window with your bat file. That makes the file visible.

I hope i helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this simpler way, please:

```
Shell "C:\Users\taischa\Desktop\test1.bat", 1
```

If it does not work, you should take the ownership of the folder in discussion. I mean, the user account who executes the code.

Is your user account an administrator type?

**Edited**:

Please, test the next code and send some feedback:

```
Sub testCreateRunBat()
 Dim FSO As Object, lngOK As Long, BT As Object
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set BT = FSO.OpenTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test.bat", 2, True)
  BT.Write "C:"
  BT.WriteLine
  BT.Write "Dir"
  BT.Close

 lngOK = Shell(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test.bat", 1)
 If lngOK <> 0 Then MsgBox "Everything OK!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru. If i execute your code i get: Runtime error 5, Invalid procedure call or invalid argument. Yes my account is an Admin accont.

Comment: @Andri This is strange... I will edit my answer and place a piece of code creating and then opening a bat file. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @Andri Did you find some time to test the code creating and running a .bat file? Is it working? If yes, this would prove the need to take the folder ownership. If it looks difficult and your account is Admin type, I can write a script to automatically take the ownership for the user running it...